# TFS2015 Check-In Copy File CI Step

Tags: build-process, tfs-2015

Is is possible to create a Continuous Integration "Build" Step in TFS2015 that simply copies a checked-in file to some file share location?  I would like to automatically copy any .xml files checked in to a TFVC project repository to a specified file share location?

Seems like it should be possible with the new TFS2015 Build System.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'd like to treat all XML files as build artifacts. There's a special build step for this called "Publish Build Artifacts". The following image illustrates how it might look for your case:

[image]

Comment: Sorry Yan.  This did not give me what I need.  The Publish Build Artifacts build step does not do anything without being associated with a Build of a project or solution file.  Either of those have the Repository mappings of files to get the sources locally on the Agent.  I don't want to pay the time price to have a solution get built successfully before a simple file copy to take place on check-in to TFVC.  Any other ideas out there?

Comment: You don't have to build the solution. If you only add one step "Publish Build Artifacts" to your definition, it will first grab the source code to the agent (you cannot disable this step), but then it won't attempt to compile it, it will just run your step and publish what you instructed it to.

Comment: Yan, you are correct, Thanks.  I was able to get the Publish Build Artifacts step to work.  But, I discovered other issues.  When Syncing the Repository, it tries do delete the artifacts directory but can't.  The files in it are ReadOnly and so the delete fails with an 'access denied' error.  The only way I could get around that was to run an 'attrib.exe' command to change the ReadOnly flag on the files and this can only run at the end of the Build Steps, not as the First step.  Seems like a bug.

Comment: Also, when the CI build starts from a checked in .xml file, I sometimes get 'The build has been queued and is waiting to start' and it may take several minutes before the Build Server Agent runs the build.  The seems like a bug too.

Comment: @Mike, when you say it tries to delete the artifacts directory, which directory do you mean? It should not touch a file share, right? I would be very surprised if it does.

Comment: Correct.  It is the artifacts directory on the build server at the C:\Agent\ _work\xxxxxxx\artifacts folder where xxxxxx is the hashed build workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible via adding a PowerShell build step. You need to define the PowerShell script to copy xml files to the shared folder.

An easy way is to call xcopy.exe command in the PowerShell file:

```
c:\windows\system32\xcopy.exe "sourcefile" "\\sharedfoler"
```

Comment: Thanks, Vicky.  That looks like another solution to my problem.  I am continuing to learn things about this new TFS2015 Build system.